# How do I get the Boot order value on an HP computer

Tags: powershell

I would like to read out my boot order settings using PowerShell. I can get those with the following script:

```
$bios = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/hp/instrumentedBIOS -Class hp_biosSetting
($bios | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Boot Order'}).Value.Split(',')
```

However, the output I get is not correct. I want just the value, but am getting the value *and* the name of the setting. For example:

```
USB Floppy  Disabled
```

The only thing I could find is to split it with an `,`, but I only want the value as output.

Comment: What do you get before splitting? `($bios | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Boot Order'}).Value`

Comment: I get all the valeus on 1 line

Comment: If you won't tell *what output you do get*, how do you expect to get help? Do you assume I'd just connect some HP iron to check out its WMI output and how to parse that?

Comment: I have an HP and dont get anything with `Name -eq "BootOrder"`. You need to show your output like vonPryz is asking. Update your question with the _actual_ output. Maybe all you need is string manipulation. We can give you an answer without it.

Comment: @Matt That WMI namespace probably isn't available without HP's [Client Management Interface](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/ads/clientmanagement/overview.html?404m=rt404Mb,newcclltow1en,rt404mb,cache-ccto0) installed.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers. Yes, i am aware of that. The point I was trying to make (now that i read it again is easily misleading) is that the OP needs to include the string output from `($bios | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Boot Order'}).Value`. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct anwser.

```
   $bios = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/hp/instrumentedBIOS -Class hp_biosSetting
$bios4 =($bios | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Legacy Boot Order'}).Value.Split(',')
echo $bios4

if ($bios4 -match "ATAPI CD-ROM Drive Disabeld"){
echo "ATAPI CD-ROM Drive =Disabeld"
$qu= "BEGIN INSERT into TESTAAD(Waarde_pcName,WAARDE_CD_ROM_BOOT) VALUES('$Waarde_pcName','Disabeld'); exception when dup_val_on_index THEN UPDATE TESTAAD SET Waarde_CD_ROM_BOOT = 'Disabeld' WHERE Waarde_pcName = '$Waarde_pcName'; END;"
$cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = $qu
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() |out-null
}
    else{
            echo " ATAPI CD-ROM Drive =Enabeld"
            $qu= "BEGIN INSERT into TESTAAD(Waarde_pcName,Waarde_CD_ROM_BOOT) VALUES('$Waarde_pcName','Enabeld'); exception when dup_val_on_index THEN UPDATE TESTAAD SET Waarde_CD_ROM_BOOT = 'Enabeld' WHERE Waarde_pcName = '$Waarde_pcName'; END;"
            $cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
            $cmd.CommandText = $qu
            $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() |out-null
        }
```