# HP Elite 8300 SFF BIOS boot order change on remote machines via Powershell

Tags: powershell, bios

Can anyone help me?  I am trying to remotely change the BIOS boot order on HP machines.  Anyone have any experience in doing this?  I can remotely set  BIOS passwords and change the general settings but am unsure how to change the boot order.

Comment: How do you proceed for the BIOS password and other settings ?

Comment: BIOS Setting change
$bios = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/hp/instrumentedBIOS -Class HP_BIOSSettingInterface
$bios.SetBIOSSetting('After Power Loss', On')                                                                                                                                                                                                                     BIOS password set
$passChange= Get -WMIObject -Namespace root\hp\instrumentedBIOS -Class HP_BIOSSettingInterface -ComputerName insertcomputername
$passChange.SetBIOSSetting('Setup Password', '<utf-16/> password')

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212969/how-do-i-get-the-boot-order-value-on-an-hp-computer ?

Comment: I saw that comment previously.  Unfortunately it doesn't talk about actually changing the boot order.  I know I just have to get the command correct.  I wanted to see if maybe someone had come across this previously for remote machines.  Thank you.

Comment: To be honest I'd probably just use [HP's BIOS Config Utility](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/caps-softpaq/cmit/HP_BCU.html) if you can push the file to the remote machine and run it on the machine(GPO?) or get their [Client Management Interface Admin Kit](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/caps-softpaq/cmit/HP_CMI_Admin_ToolKit.html) that has PS scripts included in it for you to use/reference.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell cannot change the boot order (or possibly any other BIOS settings). You can change the boot order with powershell on a VM, but I don't think that is what you want.